# Word: Can you pass MergeFields from Original Document to Embedded Document?

Tags: ms-word

[image: M]I'm wondering if there is a way to get Embedded Word Documents to have access to the Main Document's MergeFields.  We are in the Real Estate Business and Typically use MEGADOCS basically a huge word file that has multiple documents.  It's a hassle making changes to the documents since it has to be changed in all our documents for the different states we do business in.  I was trying to explore using Embedded documents that way I can make the change once and it propagate to all the documents that contain that embedded document.  However it has MergeFields in it that needs to be updated when the Main document gets ran from our software.

Current way I've tried doing it is "INSERT/Object/Object..." Create from File with the Link to File flag checked.  However this simply puts what appears to be an image of the actual document not the actual document itself (and the mergefields haven't been processed).

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Here is a image of what I get when I try running the Embedded document in the main document with MergeData.

Comment: This is not a programming question. As such it is off-topic for StackOverflow and should instead be asked in an appropriate end-user forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mailmerge fields in a document embedded in a mailmerge main document will not be processed by a mailmerge. However, mailmerge fields in a document linked via an INCLUDTETEXT field, such as Word generates when you use Insert|Object>Text from File, with the Link to File option *will* be processed by a mailmerge; the only provisos being that the linked document is not itself a mailmerge main document and that the fields it employs appear in the data source used by the parent mailmerge main document.